# R: Fast calculation of geometric means

Tags: r, performance, tree

I have a matrix of data that looks like this:

```
> df[1:5,1:5]
          OTU_97.30326 OTU_97.44566 OTU_97.44134 OTU_97.45188 OTU_97.31247 ...
700114712 0.0001197605 0.0003592814 0.0001197605 0.0001197605 0.0043113772
700114713 0.0001236400 0.0001236400 0.0001236400 0.0001236400 0.0001236400
700114554 0.0001245795 0.0001245795 0.0001245795 0.0001245795 0.0001245795
700114606 0.0001282380 0.0001282380 0.0001282380 0.0001282380 0.0001282380
700114335 0.0002158662 0.0009713977 0.0005396654 0.0001079331 0.0024824609
...
```

I also have a matrix that relates the geometric means I need to calculate to the columns of the above table.

```
> sbp[1:5,1:7]
             n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7...
OTU_97.30326  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
OTU_97.44566  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
OTU_97.44134  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
OTU_97.45188  1  1  1  0  1  1  0
OTU_97.31247  1  1  1  -1  1  0  1
...
```

Both are about 4000 by 4000 in size.

For every column n* I need to calculate the variance of the geometric mean of the first matrix (by rows) i.e., something along the lines of:

```
x <- which(sbp[,'n1']==1)
var(geometricMeanRows(df[,x]))
```

The problem is that what I wrote above is too slow to be useful. Any recommendations on how to speed this up?

**Note (if it helps):** that each n* correspond to the sign code of an internal node of a binary tree. That is sbp[,'n1'] gives a vector where all the tips that descend from the internal node 'n1' are labeled with +1 or -1 based on if they descend from the right or left subtree of n1 and 0 if it is not a descendent.

Comment: For this problem, you seem to only care about the `1` values of `sbp`. Is there any difference in behavior for the `0` and `-1` values?

Comment: I don't know where your `geometrucMeanRows` function is from, but it's probably taking the log of the whole matrix, taking the mean, and exponentiating the result every time you call it. `rowMeans` is quite efficient, so you might want to `log` your matrix in advance, then just use `var(exp(rowMeans(df[, x]))`, then you avoid taking a log at every iteration.

Comment: For even more gain, since R matrices are stored in column-major order, `colMeans` is about 3 times as fast as `rowMeans`. so transposing your matrix and operating on columns rather than rows would probably help a fair bit too.

Comment: If there is no behavioral difference between 0's and 1's, then eliminate the `which` line at each iteration by setting -1 values to 0 and just using `var(exp(colMeans(df[sbp[i, ]))` (assuming you've transposed).

Comment: And most importantly, make sure these are **matrices**. You say you have "a matrix", but when you call it `df` it makes it sound like a data frame, which will be **much slower**. Similarly, you say `sbp` is a matrix, but you index it by a column name like `sbp['n1']`, which is valid syntax for a data frame, but not for a matrix. Use actual matrices! (And be precise in your posting! Don't say *matrix* when you mean *data.frame*.)

Comment: @Gregor No, you are right, here I am only interested in the +1. Also, geometricMeanRows is just a placeholder for any function that calculates the geometric means on the rows. Yes I agree about the log first, good idea! Yes my notation is a holdover from using pandas a whole bunch in the past. They are matricies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use the **package *Rfast*** to speed up your code.

```
colGeomMean <- function(x) Rfast::colprods(x,method="expsumlog")^(1/nrow(x))
x <- which(sbp[,'n1']==1)
Rfast::Var(colGeomMean(df[,x]))
```

Here are some benchmarks for function **Rfast::Var**

```
x=rnorm(4000)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Rfast=a<-Rfast::Var(x),R=b<-var(x),times = 10)
Unit: microseconds
   expr    min     lq    mean median     uq     max neval
 Rfast  14.369 15.190 19.5417 16.627 19.296  43.927    10
     R  59.938 62.401 85.0214 68.149 99.349 167.497    10
a==b
[1] TRUE
```

Also an example using for-loop

```
x=rnorm(4000)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
Rfast=for(i in 1:1000) a<-Rfast::Var(x),R=for(i in 1:1000) b<-var(x),times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
 Rfast 16.56490 16.93438  20.27926 17.11994  18.57527  44.03719    10
     R 66.97311 73.90082 105.52192 87.81862 132.33613 207.79121    10

a==b
[1] TRUE
```

R doesn't have **colprods** so **colGeomMean** will be faster than apply the **prod** to every column. You can compare it with yours.
It is better to use method="expsumlog" to colprods. It is slower than defualt but it is safer.
Finally, **Rfast** has the function **colVars** which might be useful.